# How to see ongoing progress of my Selenium tests run in NUnit on Jenkins?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, nunit, .net

I am running my tests in Selenium using NUnit and Jenkins and it takes more then 2 hours to run all tests.

I want to see the progress of the tests for monitoring if everything is OK like a team city build

I installed the Test In Progress Report plugin but it doesn't work with NUnit

Comment: Are you working with a single build server? You might look at distributing your tests across multiple servers via jobs to get a faster response time. As far as I can tell from a quick search, the only other option available to you is to extend either Jenkins (by building your own plugin) or the In Progress plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the test progress in logs, you just need to add Execution details in your SetUp and TearDown like this:

```
private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _stopwatch.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Running: {0}", TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName);
}

[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    _stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Execution time: {0}", _stopwatch.Elapsed);
    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
     // Screenshot generation
    _stopwatch.Reset();
}
```